# .gitignore file not working properly

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the following .gitignore file:

```
# Ignore everything
*

# But not these
!.gitignore
!Code
!Materials
```

The intention is to ignore everything except the .gitignore file itself, and everything under the Code and Materials directories.  Somehow when I open SourceTree, the .gitignore file is properly excluded, but the Code and Materials directories are ignored.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` matches every file in those directories as well (and Git doesn’t keep track of empty directories). You can ignore just the top level:

```
# Ignore everything
/*

# But not these
!/.gitignore
!/Code
!/Materials
```

Paths like `/Code/example.cs` won’t be matched by `/*`, because `*` can only represent one path component, but a simple `*` without the `/` *will* match the `example.cs` component of `/Code/example.cs`.

Comment: Thank you so much.  That fixes it.